# Word for "about the way everything is connected"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for "about how everything is connected"? As "holistic" is about everything, I would like a word that is about everything but draws attention to the way that each thing affects the other things.

The holistic analysis is about the large red circle, the topics/points involved, the _____ analysis is more so about the lines (relationships) in-between everything.

[image]

> Here are three paintings. A ___ exploration of them reveals...

(Common themes the paintings share, how they may have directly or indirectly influenced each other, forces that shaped the artists' lives and how each held similar, derived, or distinct world views. How the forces that shaped the artists lives connect with each other, how the media available to the artists was different because of technological progress etc.)

Comment: IMO the example with paintings you added on is not well served by the diagram, which shows only all *pairs* of paintings but excludes all larger groupings for analysis. For example for the set of all paintings in a museum room, you might want to analyze them using groupings by country of origin, period, medium, subject, etc.-- not just in pairs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132532/discussion-on-question-by-theonlygusti-word-for-about-the-way-everything-is-con).

Answer (score 2):

*Here are three paintings. A **relational** exploration of them reveals . . .*

> **relational**
>  <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Concerning the way in which two or more people or things are
> connected.
>  <sub>*power is a relational concept that can only be
> understood in terms of interactions between individuals and
> groups*</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *relational*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/relational)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> The holistic analysis is about the large red circle, the topics/points
> involved, the **configuration** [analysis] is more so about the lines
> (relationships) in-between everything.

(If you use *configuration*, *configurational analysis* may be unnecessary. Note that *configuration* includes the position of the points on the circle as well.)

**configuration** (n.) /

> Arrangement of parts or elements in a particular form or figure; the
> form, shape, figure, resulting from such arrangement; conformation;
> outline, contour (of geographical features, etc.). OED

> Something (such as a figure, contour, pattern, or apparatus) that
> results from a particular arrangement of parts or components [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/configuration)

> **Configuration (geometry)** In mathematics, specifically projective geometry, a configuration in the plane consists of a finite set of
> **points**, and a finite arrangement of **lines**, such that each point is
> incident to the same number of lines and each line is incident to the
> same number of points.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_(geometry))

---

> [image: Configuration]
> A possible **configuration** of points for
> Example 2.30 with *n*=8. [David Hunter; *Essentials of Discrete
> Mathematics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Essentials_of_Discrete_Mathematics/C4WHCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=configuration%20of%20lines%20connecting%20the%20points%20on%20a%20circle&pg=PA100&printsec=frontcover)

> These requirements suggest identifying only recurrent or stable
> **configurations** of the underlying "network of neurons" as being memorized—in contrast to temporary or transient **configurations.**
> [Giorgio Ascoli et al.; *Brain Informatics and Health*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Brain_Informatics_and_Health/35coDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=configuration%20network%20neuron%20brain&pg=PA62&printsec=frontcover)

> The result has been an improvised, constantly fluctuating, often
> unreliable, and little understood **configuration** of water flow in
> the city. [Lisa Björkman; *Pipe Politics, Contested Waters*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pipe_Politics_Contested_Waters/MqGQCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=pipes%20in%20a%20city%20configuration&pg=PT11&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: This seems to work only with physical things and direct relationships. I find it hard to use about abstract themes, I've just specified an example in my question that I think this doesn't quite work for.

Comment: IMO your painting example is not served by a diagram that shows  lines representing only all *pairs* of paintings to the exclusion of larger groupings.